# Can't send HTTP with axios even set android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" and network security config in React native

Tags: android, react-native, axios

I was trying to communicate with my server using Axios. I checked it worked well in the same URL, same body data in Postman. However, in most conditions, the application doesn't make an HTTP call - It only works when I turn on network inspector in [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) with debug mode. make a bunch of error messages like below.

```
Error: Network Error at createError 
(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.wheelie&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:115372:17) at EventTarget.handleError
(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.wheelie&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:115282:16) at EventTarget.dispatchEvent
(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.wheelie&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:33554:27) at EventTarget.setReadyState
(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.wheelie&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:32692:20) at EventTarget.__didCompleteResponse
(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.wheelie&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:32500:16) at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.wheelie&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:32616:47 at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit
(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.wheelie&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:2310:37) at MessageQueue.__callFunction
(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.wheelie&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3348:31) at http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.wheelie&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3076:17 at MessageQueue.__guard
(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.wheelie&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:3302:13)
```

I read the article that android network policy may be the reason.  I changed the `AndroidManifest.xml` below. Then I checked there is `http://` or `https://` in a domain,  and there was no problem with the domain. Finally, I added `network_security_config.xml`, but it doesn't make a change.

I use my physical android phone(galaxy A50, android 11) instead of AVD. `targetSdkVersion` and `complieSdkVersion` are also API 30, `minSdkVersion` is 22.

`postLogIn`

```js
export function postLogIn(authorizationInfo: WheelieAuthorizationInfo) {
  return axios.post<{
    statusCode: number;
    token: string;
  }>(`${domain}/account/login`, authorizationInfo);
}
```

`app/src/debug/AndrodiManifest.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        tools:targetApi="28"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

`network_security_config.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
            <certificates src="user" />
        </trust-anchors>
        
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem two days ago by adding `network_security_config.xml` and network certificates(`*.pem`) for my backend API server.

References: [Andorid Dev Network Security Configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config)

First, add a custom networking security setting in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
...
<application
      ...
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

Second, make `./android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <network-security-config>
    <domain-config>
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">pedalers.net</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
          <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
        </trust-anchors>
      </domain-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <!-- Without localhost setting, it's unable to connect metro with app. -->
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
      <!-- For physical phone, 10.0.0.1 is the address connect to computer -->
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.0.1</domain>
      <!-- For AVD, 10.0.2.2 is the address connect to computer -->
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
  </network-security-config>
```

Third, add the self-signed or non-public CA certificate, in PEM or DER format, to `res/raw/my_ca`.

Comment: The root cause of this situation is CA of Let's encrypt was expired. My team changed the SSL service and fix it, so I deleted `network_security_config.xml`.